# Database view hibernate mapping

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I am using a Hibernate mapping of my database view (view1), and it contains another view (view2). It works, but I get many requests to the database and I want to optimize this. What is the problem?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "view1")
public class View1 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "operation", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private View2 view2;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "view2")
public class View2 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "operation")
    private Long operation;
...
}
```

The next JPQL query generate too much requests.

```
select e from View1 e left join fetch e.view2
```

Generated native SQL, repeated more than 60 times

```
select view20_.id as id1_221_0_, view20_.operation as operati16_221_0_
```

Comment: you are not creating a view, you are creating a table

Comment: @SpringLearner This is a view in the existing database.

Comment: this is not a view, this is a table.

Comment: I think that's not the problem. It works well with JPA.

Comment: @SpringLearner All the annotation says is store this in a JPA "table". The JPA provider can map that on to an RDBMS View if they wish. As for the question, you present no information about the "problem". It's inefficient? so what? define where it is inefficient, by quoting SQL invoked.